# Objective-C Post request send no data

Tags: objective-c, post, http-post

I'm trying to send post request to an url

but the server always get empty data

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cmd=login&account=%@&password=%@" ,account ,password];
NSData *data = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSMutableData *postData = [data mutableCopy];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myurl.com"]]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSError *error = nil;
NSHTTPURLResponse* urlResponse = nil;
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&error];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", returnString);
NSLog(@"error: %@", error.localizedFailureReason);
```

here is the response

2014-08-18 17:21:52.332 SignPos[2755:303] {"resp":99,"desc":"invalid cmd"}

2014-08-18 17:21:52.333 SignPos[2755:303] error: (null)

is there anything wrong?

thanks!

Comment: add a NSError object to valid what went wrong in the request...

Comment: I add NSError but no error appear.

Comment: could you update your code snippet and add the http header response

Comment: Your request has returned a response, not the one your looking for... i can only assume your url parameters or hhtp header is incorrect. i suggest you install a mac application like [CocoaRestClient](http://code.google.com/p/cocoa-rest-client/) or use curl to see if all the information you provided is correct